# Using Google_Http_Batch to insert multiple events

Tags: google-api-php-client

I do multiple inserts using this code snippet:

```
foreach ($aFile as $v) {
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary($v[7]);

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($v[0]);
    $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($v[1]);
    $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $new_event = null;

    try {
        $new_event = $service->events->insert($calName, $event);
        $new_event_id= $new_event->getId();
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, $e->getMessage());
    }

    $event = $service->events->get($calName, $new_event->getId());

    }
}
```

The events are successfully inserted but it take ages for large set of events. Typically about 45 sec. for 50 inserts. And, my high speed internet connection is not to blame.

Is there a way to use the [Google_Http_Batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch) class to speed up the insert process and how?

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found how to do that batch event upload. Easier that I thought:

```
    $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

    foreach ($aEvents as $k => $v) {
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
        $event->setSummary($v[6]);

        $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $start->setDateTime($v[4]);
        $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
        $event->setStart($start);

        $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $end->setDateTime($v[5]);
        $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
        $event->setEnd($end);

        $new_event = null;

        /* add event inserts in the batch spool */
        $req = $service->events->insert($calName, $event);
        $batch->add($req, $k);
    }

    /* executing the batch and storing the results */
    $resultsBatch = $batch->execute();
```

The `$batch->execute()` method returns an array of objects containing the Google API responses to the inserts.